# On ajax page script don't work. Any workaround

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a page with list of items on it , on clicking any one of item ajax call is send to get the response from the server, on the response page there are script included("inline"), as it is response text that script doesn't get fired("because browser doesn't detect a page refresh")is there any workaround for firing the script on the ajax response page.
i tried using eval() but it makes the page unresponsive for few seconds(" hinders the site performance") is there any other technique.

This is response i call from ajax call , this response had a script to show a player, but the script on this page doesn't get fired.

```
<div class="audiomodule unlocked">
                <div id="locked" class="icon_holder">
                </div>
                <div class="text_box">
                    <p>Listen to Audio</p>
                    <p class="secondline">SLIDE 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="audioholder">

        <div id="flashcontent1270162253375"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
includeJWPlayerEmbed('http://172.200.88.55/player-licensed-54.swf','http://172.200.88.55/funds/skins/glow.zip', null, 'http://Healthcare-CurrentEconomicOverview.mp3', 'Healthcare-CurrentEconomicOverview.mp3', 'false', 'sound', '28', '222', 'flashcontent127','null');
            </script><div class="date floatLeft" style="display:inline;">Updated as of: 12/31/11</div>

                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                 window.onunload = function()
                {
                 clearplayerCode("audioholder");
                }
                </script>
                <div class="button_holder">
                    <div class="login_button"><a href="#"><span>Login</span></a></div>

    </div>
<div class="clear"></div>                           


</div>
```

Comment: Please show some code as I have no idea what you are trying to say

Comment: I posted the code have a look

Answer (score 1):

`eval` doesn't 'hinder performance' in itself. It is your code that takes a long time to execute.

The best way to achieve your goal is not to send the javascript in response but have it included in the page and just call it from ajax success handler. You might want to send some parameters back from the server, so they can be passed to the script.

Comment: Can you please provide me some example of how to achieve that.

Comment: Can't help much without seeing your code. Start by putting whatever script you return in ajax call on the page and call it from the place where you were `eval`ing it.

Answer (score 0):

without using `eval()` you could dynamically inject the response text (the javascript code)  inside a `<script>` element that you could append into your document (e.g. in the `<body>` element)

see [this example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg2gA/) in action

Comment: As i wrote, that code it's just a conceptual example you can easily write with every js framework (also in plain js only).

Comment: Where is this js file getting including either on main page or ajax response page